# How to configure Restcomm jSS7 to receive and send dialogs from same SccpAddress

Tags: restcomm, mobicents, ss7

I have JAIN-SLEE application which runs on Restcomm SLEE.
Application receives and sends USSD messages placing as Calling Party SccpAddress with AI=18 (pc, ssn, tt, digits).

Now I would like to set up Restcomm Simulator and JBoss stack to reveive and send USSD from both sides.

Is it possible to configure simulator as client and server at the same time?

Do I need to create SCTP client association and server associations in JBoss?

How to configure PC and SSN to be same for both sctp associations?